# How to handle MSAL SSO using jmeter? How to create NONCE and STATE values dynamically

Tags: jmeter, state, single-sign-on, msal.js, nonce

I'm trying to script the msal sso login wherein i need to send nonce and state value dynamically.

The nonce value is something i am able to handle by using jmeter function ${__UUID()}.
Can someone let me know how can genereate state value which starts from ey

Answer (score 0):

As per [Pass custom state in authentication requests using MSAL.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-pass-custom-state-authentication-request)

> The state parameter, as defined by OAuth 2.0, is included in an authentication request and is also returned in the token response to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks. **By default, the Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript (MSAL.js) passes a randomly generated unique state parameter value** in the authentication requests.

So if this is the case just call [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) function another time there or use something like [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString)

If your application developers implemented custom logic around this `state` parameter you will need to do it as well using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).